# How can I reference an external project with Catkin?

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to build a ROS node that uses some code from an external project.  I certainly need to reference some header files from that project, and will probably also need to "pull in" some C++ source code from that project.

The simplest, dumbest, least maintainable way I could to this would be to simply copy the header file(s) and source file(s) into my ROS project.

I feel like there should be some way to tell Catkin or Cmake "Add this directory to the list of includes" and "Add that directory to VPATH".  But, as Catkin and Cmake are totally new to me (as of about a week ago), I haven't the foggiest idea how to ask the Google to find the answer to my question.  So I'll ask the community instead :-)

Thanks for any tips you can give me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189223/how-can-i-reference-an-external-project-with-catkin?/) by [wpd](https://answers.ros.org/users/19918/wpd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 249 on 2014-08-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) on 2014-08-06**:
Do the external projects use cmake? If they provide a cmake config file, you can find_package them just like opencv: http://wiki.ros.org/vision_opencv

**Comment by [wpd](https://answers.ros.org/users/19918/wpd/) on 2014-08-06**:
Unfortunately, it does not.  It is a traditional Make based project.  I would like to pull a few header files and source files from that project into mine.

**Comment by [wpd](https://answers.ros.org/users/19918/wpd/) on 2014-08-06**:
So far, I have started down the path of writing my own "Findtrunk.cmake" file to find the project in my source tree (which I keep separate from my budding ROS source tree... for the moment) ,defining ${TRUNK_DIR} in Findtrunk.cmake, and adding ${TRUNK_DIR}/include to include_directories().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All right, here is what I did.  I feel like it is tremendously hacky, but it appears to work.

I created a `cmake_modules/Findtrunk.cmake` file containing:

```
#invented based on what I found in libfreenect/cmake_modules/Findlibusb-1.0.cmake
if (TRUNK_DIR)
  # in cache already
  set(TRUNK_FOUND TRUE)
else (TRUNK_DIR)
  find_path(TRUNK_DIR
    NAMES
    rcp/Makefile
    PATHS
        $ENV{HOME}/src/hai/trunk
  )

  if (TRUNK_DIR)
    set(TRUNK_FOUND TRUE)
  endif (TRUNK_DIR)

  if (TRUNK_FOUND)
    if (NOT trunk_FIND_QUIETLY)
      message(STATUS "Found trunk:")
      message(STATUS " - ${TRUNK_DIR}")
    endif (NOT trunk_FIND_QUIETLY)
  else (TRUNK_FOUND)
    if (trunk_FIND_REQUIRED)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find trunk")
    endif (trunk_FIND_REQUIRED)
  endif (TRUNK_FOUND)

endif (TRUNK_DIR)
```

I added the following 2 snippets to my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules/")
find_package(trunk REQUIRED)
```

and

```
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${TRUNK_DIR}/common/include
  ${TRUNK_DIR}/this/that
  ${TRUNK_DIR}/the/other/thing
)
set(BBR_FILES
  ${TRUNK_DIR}/this/that/buffer.c
  ${TRUNK_DIR}/this/that/config.c
)
set_source_files_properties(${BBR_FILES} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)

add_executable(mp2ros_node
  src/mp2ros_node.cpp
  ${BBR_FILES}
)
```

and that seems to work.  I'm not sure it's the most straightforward thing to do.  I like the idea of creating a `Findtrunk.cmake` file so that others on my team might edit it to reflect the location of their `trunk` directory.  We'll see if that ever comes to pass.

I would appreciate any questions, comments, or snide remarks more experienced folks would care to make regarding this approach.  I'm certain that I'm not following any number of standard Cmake conventions (I noticed that other Findxxx.cmake files define INCLUDE_XXX_DIRS, for example), but this seems to work for me so far.

---

Originally posted by [wpd](https://answers.ros.org/users/19918/wpd/) with karma: 249 on 2014-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) on 2014-08-07**:
This seems like a good approach. Thanks for posting this!

**Comment by [zultron](https://answers.ros.org/users/34470/zultron/) on 2018-07-18**:
Setting `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` is forbidden in the ROS [CMake Coding Standards](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/user_guide/standards.html) document, although it doesn't say what folks should do in this case.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-03**:
I don't recall why that was added to the docs (https://github.com/ros/catkin/commit/f8757cb248f255df49365a98b13f3917a132ad18#diff-4ad8521ab1ee054b80370475d0786563R134). Maybe the original author remembers?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-03**:
The approach to extend the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` locally in your CMake seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to use an external project you should never pull in c++ code. Just make it a library and use pkg-config. Have a look at [this page on how to write pc files](http://people.freedesktop.org/%7Edbn/pkg-config-guide.html) (very easy).

Afterwards you can just use:

```
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(ARBITRARYNAME my_library-1.0)
...
include_directories(
 include
 ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
 ${ARBITRARYNAME_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
...
target_link_libraries(my_node
 ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
 ${ARBITRARYNAME_LIBRARIES}
)
```

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2014-08-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wpd](https://answers.ros.org/users/19918/wpd/) on 2014-08-07**:
Thanks for the idea.  Unfortunately, I cannot easily modify the external project right now.  Hence the reason I'm trying to just pull in a few of the source files into my project.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-08-13**:
This is a good approach for most libraries, because they usually *do* support pkg-config.